# How can I set up the ULOG target with iptables and MySQL

Tags: iptables, firewall

I'm running CentOS 6.6 32bit as a firewall box using iptables.

I want to be able to use the ULOG target to store dropped packets in a MySQL database for statistical analysis.

After much Googling I can't really see how this is achieved or if it's even possible. I tried seeing if my kernel will support it

`grep ULOG /boot/config-2.6.32-504.el6.i686
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_ULOG=m
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_ULOG=m`

Which I think is telling that there is support? But I have no idea how to set this up, and most guides on the internet are very outdated or do not work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

[See here](http://www.stearns.org/doc/iptables-ulog.v0.1.html). You need a `ulogd` utility, available at least in Debian as the `ulogd` package; you can also install `ulogd-mysql` for logging into MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/404099/42520), ULOG target is obsolete and it was replaced by target NFLOG. You should try an iptables rule like the following:

`IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -j NFLOG`