# iptables: No chain/target/match ULOG

Tags: kernel, iptables, logs, firewall

I want to use `ULOG` and send firewall logs to `ulogd2`

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j   ULOG
```

gives me following error:

```
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name
```

I have these LOG-related options enabled in my kernel:

```
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_LOG=y
CONFIG_NF_LOG_COMMON=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_LOG=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_NFLOG=y
CONFIG_NF_LOG_IPV4=y
```

What else do I need for ULOG to work ?

I don't see any ULOG options (nothing found when I search for ULOG)

My kernel is 4.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ULOG has been deprecated, and if you don't have module `ipt_ULOG` you should move on to the newer NFLOG target. `ulogd` handles both of these, even though it is still called "ulog". Check out [man iptables-extensions](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html).